# Elastic Search: Covariant in DocumentApi

Tags: elasticsearch

When searching for documents covariance has great support as described here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/covariant-search-results.html

But what about the Document Api? - does it support covariance?

Example from Sense where all works:

```
PUT demo_covariant/car/1
{
  "carname":"ford"
}

PUT demo_covariant/boat/2
{
  "boatname":"speedy"
}

GET demo_covariant/boat,car/_search
{
"query": {"match_all": {}}
}

GET demo_covariant/boat/2
GET demo_covariant/car/1
```

But when it comes to querying multiple indexes this will not produce any results:

```
GET demo_covariant/boat,car/2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the "_all" types descriped here: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#type

Works:

```
GET demo_covariant/_all/2
```